# How to make a dynamic (add/remove) carousel in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, blazor, maui

I am making a CarouselView in Xamarin (Maui Blazor). It is intended that each item represents a day (starting from the present), and the user can swipe between days chronologically. I wish to be able to dynamically remove and add items to my carousel as the user navigates through the days, so that the collection behind does not become too large, ideally staying at either three or five entries or something similiar.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="carousel" 
                  Loop="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding .}">
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>
```

I have a property for the collection...

```
public ObservableCollection<BlazorWebView> ItemCollection { get; set; }
```

...and then methods to set up the carousel:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<BlazorWebView> itemCollection = new ObservableCollection<BlazorWebView>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        itemCollection.Add(SetUpBlazorWebView(i));
    }

    ItemCollection = itemCollection;

    BindingContext = this;
}

public BlazorWebView SetUpBlazorWebView(int counterParameter)
{
    BlazorWebView blazor = new BlazorWebView()
    {
        HostPage = "wwwroot/index.html"
    };

    blazor.RootComponents.Add(new RootComponent()
    {
        ComponentType = typeof(Pages.Counter),
        Selector = "#app",
        Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "CurrentCount", counterParameter} }
    });

    return blazor;
}
```

(Pages.Counter is just the default Blazor counter component modified so that the currentCount is a parameter)
This all works fine, however it has 100 items.
So far I have tried binding the position to a property that modifies the collection through the setter depending on whether the new position is higher or lower. This does not work, specifically modifying the collection from within the setter.

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this problem? Or possibly a different approach as I am aware that I may be making some fundamental mistakes with regards to my approach to the problem.

Comment: Indeed, you are making a fundamental mistake. The only place that should have `BlazorWebView` is the `ItemTemplate`. `itemCollection` should contain either URIs or HTML strings, depending on your situation. Currently, you are creating 100 WebViews; not practical.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Does the template not duplicate the `BlazorWebView` for each item anyway? I originally had implemented it that way but I ran into issues with specifying the type of component in a sub-directory through `ComponentType`. This still does not solve the original issue either.

Comment: Template only creates as many views as are visible (perhaps some extra for scrolling). E.g. on Android, it is built on `RecyclerView`. But you are right, that doesn't solve your issue. What's "hard" about what you have, is the need to pass information between what's "inside" blazor (the Counter component), and what's "outside of" blazor (all the other c#, and Maui widgets). This is an `interop` problem: "How share data between .Net MAUI and Blazor". I haven't seen an official Microsoft doc about that. For now, see [maui blazor](https://egvijayanand.in/2021/11/16/dotnet-maui-blazor-interop/).

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the suggestions. I don't quite see how this is an `interop` problem though. Passing data from Maui to Blazor is fine through the `Paramaters` of the `RootComponent`, I don't need data back. I would have this problem even without the Blazor stuff. I'm using Blazor because I wish to improve my Blazor skills, and be able to use libraries I know like MudBlazor, however I want to use Xamarin for the native touch support on the carousel.

Comment: Then I misunderstood what you said. Does your question show the code that "does not work"? If so, which line of code is it? If not, please add it to the question.